# git downloading the live to the local

Tags: git, github

Having a bit of bother with the following

I am working in a directory such like

> cd ~/RepoPlugin

I have edited a file and when I try push it to github it comes back

> rejected master -> master (non-fast-forward)

So I tried the following inside my RepoPlugin directory

> git pull

This did not update my local files

So I resorted to editing my file on the github website. But I can't seem to sync things up anymore.

I don't want to fork anything, I just want to download what changes has been made on the website to the local directory.

Comment: If `git pull` does not bring in the changes from the remote something is not right. How did you obtain the clone of the directory?

Answer (score 1):

Specify more precisely what you want to pull, I've had this happen a few times and simply stating the origin and master works every time, when `git pull` fails.

`git pull origin master`